# XMC module in electronics industry

Tags: hardware

What does XMC module stand for in hardware engineering?

I have seen industry mention this but does it have a fullform?

Comment: Welcome to DSP.SE! This is not really a DSP.SE question. It's more a EE.SE question, I think

Answer (score 1):

I found it on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Mezzanine_Card

> **XMC**, or **Switched Mezzanine Card**, (PMC with high-speed serial fabric interconnect) defined by the VITA 42 standard. XMC specifies a fifth connector ("P15") that supports PCI Express (VITA 42.3) or other high speed serial formats such as Serial RapidIO (VITA 42.2) and Parallel RapidIO (VITA 42.1).

Looks like the acronym used X instead of S, perhaps to avoid confusion with SMC connectors.